# error parsing string to int -java.lang.NumberFormatExceptiont

Tags: numberformatexception

I'm parsing a String to an Integer and I get the following error:

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input
>   string: "9887666881"

**code**

```
long accountNo=0;
if(accountNo_p!=null)
   accountNo=Integer.parseInt(accountNo_p);
```

can you please advise?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Java's `int` size is 32 bits wide. The maximum value for a (signed) 32-bit integer in Java's format is 2,147,483,647. The input string is 9,887,666,881. The input is larger than the maximum value for a Java `int`, so it throws a `NumberFormatException` (since you're using the `Integer` method for `parseInt`, not a method to parse a `long`).

Solutions include using smaller numbers (if this is a wild test case, not real data), or using a Java `long` (via `Long.parseLong(accountNo_p)`).